# Determine the quantity of unique increasing values within a range

Tags: excel-formula

I am attempting to write a formula that will identify the number of supplements that I have received on any specific contract.  These numbers should be increasing in value in excess of $100 greater than the previous value and ignoring blank cells.  Ex:

```
 Year            2014  2015  2016  2017  2018   2019     Quantity should be
Contract #1     $1000 $1001 $3000 $5000  $4000  BLANK            2
Contract #2     BLANK BLANK $5000 $8000  $8000  $7000            1
```

In this scenario, there were 2 values that meet the requirements

This is my most recent attempt at an equation

```
=COUNTIF($DF3:$DK3,">"&DF3+100)+COUNTIF($DF3:DF3,DF3)-1
```

However, it does not account for if there is a reduction in the sale at the end of the project.

Comment: Would you be able to clarify what result is expected, please? I'm not able to understand it.

Comment: I only see 2 that increase greater than 100 and is not blank.  2016 and 2017.

Comment: Kaiser, the intention is to determine when there have been funds added to a contract value of a series of 4000 data points.  This is one example for what a project could look like over the course of 5 years.

@Scott Craner, you are correct.  There are two values that meet the requirement.

Comment: Can you use a helper row?  What happens if 2016 is blank but the rest are not?  does 2017 need to compare to 2015?

Comment: is it the word blank or is it actually an empty cell or does it have "".  Empty cells return ISBLANK() TRUE where "" cells returns ISBLANK() FALSE.

Comment: I want to go with `SUMPRODUCT($DG3:$DK3-$DF3:$DJ3>100)` but I am not sure how to deal with the blank scenario

Comment: The blank will either be at the beginning or the end of the string depending on what year the project started.  Therefore, it could be blank for 2014 and 2015 then have data in 2016-2019.  I've made additions to the information above to represent the statement.

Comment: Helper rows are fine... the data mining portion of the spreadsheet is for my use only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Assumption the blank only occurs at the end, last year**
- **Values in being counted can only be positive entries**

Lets assume the blank value is in DK3.

IF the blank is actually an empty cell.  In other words if ISBLANK(DK3) = TRUE then you can use the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($DG3:$DK3-$DF3:$DJ3>100))
```

If ISBLANK(DK3) = FALSE then use the following formula and enter it as an array formula using <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(IFERROR($DG3:$DK3-$DF3:$DJ3,0)>100))
```

#### DK3 is blank

[image: Blank]

#### DK3 is not blank

[image: Not Blank]

#### Helper Row Option

In a helper row use the following formula:

=IF(DG3<>"Blank",--(DG3-DF3>100),0)

I placed that in DG8 and copied to the right.  It places 1 where your condition is true, and 0 when its false.  Then just take the sum of the row.

#### UPDATE - BLANKS at start of row

IF you are dealing with truly blank cell in column DF then adjust the formula as follows:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($DG3:$DK3-$DF3:$DJ3>100))-ISBLANK($DF3)
```

Comment: I see where you are going with this.  Is there a way to exclude it from counting cell DJ3 because it is less than cell DI3?  Each consecutive cell should be larger than the one before (only count years where the contract value increase by >$100 compared to the previous year).

Comment: It already is excluding DJ3 because its negative 1000 not just 1000 difference.  only when the difference is positive 100 greater does it get counted.  That is why the answer is 2.  (2016 and 2017)

Comment: I see! I had a small typo in copying the equation as well which corrected what I thought was wrong.  Thank you so much!

Comment: HA my formula is smarter than me!  I thought it wold not work with your second case with blank at the start but it does.  Basically what it is doing is treating every operation that involves blank a 0 which is always less than 100.  I originally thought it was converting blank to 0 which is something else.  the CSE formula is the better one to use.  Not that if those blanks are truly empty, the formula will treat them as 0 in which case your count for the second row  sample data will be off by 1 .  This can be adjusted by adding `-ISBLANK($DF3)` to the end of the formula

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with helper columns should be pretty straight forward:

[image]

Create a new row and paste the formula (cell DF6) is:

```
=+IF(ISERROR(IF(DF3-DE3>100,1,0)),0,IF(DF3-DE3>100,1,0))
```

Then, just a total with SUM() will give you the totals (formula for cell DM6):

```
=+SUM(DF6:DK6)
```

It works with Blank cells and "BLANK" cells as well.